# c vector sort separate file in .h .cpp

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm struggling with vector sort.. I've came across an [example found online](http://ideone.com/Eikbr4) earlier on and I tried to do something on my own but somehow things are not going well and I've read lots of reference online but they all place the "sort" function in the main function..

What I'm trying out is to see if I can use include sort inside a function.

missionplan.h

```
class MissionPlan
{
   friend struct stortByCiv;
    private:
        int sizeofarray;
        int sizeofarray2;
        int xcordi;
        int ycordi;



    public:
        MissionPlan();
        MissionPlan(int, int, float);

        int getx();
        int gety();
        float getciv();

        void stats();
        void storedata(int, int, float);
        void test();
        void displayall();
        void compute();
        void topfives();

        float civnum;

}
struct sortByCiv 
 { void f(MissionPlan &p){ p.civnum = getciv();};
bool operator()(MissionPlan const &t1, MissionPlan const &t2) { return t1.civnum < t2.civnum; }
```

};
;

missionplan.cpp

```
#include "LocationData.h"
#include "PointTwoD.h"
#include "MissionPlan.h"


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

    vector <PointTwoD> point1;//set PointTwoD object as a vector array, name of array "point1"
    vector <PointTwoD> topfive;
    LocationData locationdata;
    PointTwoD pointtwoD;
    MissionPlan missionplan;

MissionPlan::MissionPlan()
{
    xcordi = 0;
    ycordi = 0;
    civnum = 0;
}

MissionPlan::MissionPlan(int x, int y, float civ)
{
    xcordi = x;
    ycordi = y;
    civnum = civ;
}   

int MissionPlan::getx()
{
    return pointtwoD.getxcord();
}

int MissionPlan::gety()
{
    return pointtwoD.getycord();
}

float MissionPlan::getciv()
{
    return locationdata.getCivIndex();
}

void MissionPlan::stats()
{
    string sunType;
    int earth;
    int moon;
    float particle;
    float plasma;
    int xcord;
    int ycord;

    cout<< "X axis: ";
    cin >> xcord;
    pointtwoD.setxcord(xcord);

    cout<< "y axis: ";
    cin >> ycord;
    pointtwoD.setycord(ycord);

    cout << "Suntype: ";
    cout.flush();//flush getline problem
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, sunType);
    locationdata.setsunType(sunType);

    cout << "No of Earth Like Planets: ";
    cin >> earth;
    locationdata.setnoOfEarthLikePlanets(earth);

    cout << "No of Earth Like Moons: ";
    cin >> moon;
    locationdata.setnoOfEarthLikeMoons(moon);

    cout << "Ave Particle Density: ";
    cin >> particle;
    locationdata.setaveParticulateDensity(particle);

    cout << "Ave Plasma Density: ";
    cin >> plasma;
    locationdata.setavePlasmaDensity(plasma);


    locationdata.computeCivIndex(sunType, earth, moon, particle, plasma);
    missionplan.test();
    missionplan.displayall();
}

void MissionPlan::test()
{

        int xcord = pointtwoD.getxcord();
        int ycord = pointtwoD.getycord();
        float civIndex = locationdata.getCivIndex();
        pointtwoD.setPointDetail(xcord, ycord, civIndex);
        point1.push_back(pointtwoD);//push/store new object into array

}



void MissionPlan::topfives()
{   

topfive.assign( point1.begin(), point1.end() ); 

sort(topfive.begin(), topfive.end(), sortByCiv);

for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    topfive.at(i).displayPointdata();
}


 }
```

Comment: You can't define a function in another function.

Comment: You should try to make a small example containing enough code to reproduce the error, but no more. Most of the code here is irrelevant.

Comment: so the only way is to do my own manual sort? @chris

Answer (score 3):

The problem right now is that you've tried to define `sortByCiv` nested inside of `topfives`. You can't define one function inside of another like that.

You have a couple of choices here. One (that works with essentially any compiler) is to define your `sortByCiv` outside of `topfives`:

```
bool sortByCiv(const  PointTwoD &t1, const  PointTwoD &t2)
{
    return t1.getciv < t2.getciv;
}

void MissionPlan::topfives() { 
    topfive.assign( point1.begin(), point1.end() ); 

    sort(topfive.begin(), topfive.end(), sortByCiv);
    // ...
 }
```

Another possibility (that is sometimes preferred is to define your comparison as a class or struct that overloads `operator()`:

```
struct sortByCiv {
    bool operator()(PointTwoD const &t1, PointTwoD const &t2) { 
        return t1.getciv < t2.getciv;
    }
};
```

When you use this, you need to add a pair of parens to the name to create an instance of the class that will be passed when sorting:

```
sort(topfive.begin(), topfive.end(), sortByCiv());
```

The final possibility (that only works with relatively recent compilers is to use a "lambda" expression:

```
void MissionPlan::topfives() { 
    topfive.assign( point1.begin(), point1.end() ); 

    sort(topfive.begin(), topfive.end(),
         [](PointTD const &t1, PointTwoD const &t2) {return t1.getciv < t2.getciv; });
    // ...
 }
```

If your compiler supports it, the lambda expression is *usually* preferred, as it lets you specify the sorting criteria "in place".

Although it's not related to the sorting, your code to display the results looks somewhat borked as well. I *think* what you want is something closer to:

```
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    topfive.at(i).displayPointdata();
```

Comment: sorry cause i'm still really new to c++ because I trying to sort them base on CIV value and my civ in actually Private so how to i access it?

Comment: @koi_s3ng: You could make it public, add an accessor, or make `MissionPlan` a friend of `PointTwoD`. If PointTwoD doesn't enforce any constraints on the `civ` value, I'd just make it public.

Comment: @koi_s3ng You have declared a `getciv` accessor.  You would simply call those in your lambda function to do the comparison:  `return t1.getciv() < t2.getciv();`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks Jerry, I've just edit the code in the que and are marked by **.. could you help me do a check if this is the right way? really appreciate your help...

Comment: Looks reasonable -- but for the sake of others looking at this question later, how about if you revert the edit, and add the modified code at the end, so somebody else reading it later can see what the problem was and how you fixed it?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Sorry to trouble you, actually place the struct sortByCiv() in my .h file and class MissionPlan is a friend of struct sortByCIV().. did I do something wrong cos I'm having compilation error.. member function 'void sortByCiv::f<MissionPlan&>' error 'getciv' was not declared in this scope..

Comment: @koi_s3ng: the `getciv` was just copied from your code--I'd assumed it was part of your `PointTwoD` class, but since didn't include that, I can't really make an intelligent guess about it.

Comment: @koi_s3ng: Sorry, but I really can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with *calling* `std::sort` from within another function.  There is something wrong with attempting to declare a function inside another function (nested functions are not supported in C++).  Thus, the following code will not compile:

```
oid MissionPlan::topfives()
{   
    bool sortByCiv(const PointTwoD &t1, const  PointTwoD  &t2);

    // ...

    bool sortByCiv(const  PointTwoD &t1, const  PointTwoD &t2)
    {
        return t1.getciv < t2.getciv;
    }
}
```

You can either declare `sortByCiv` outside of the `topfives` function (either as a class member or as a standalone function - though it would need to be a `friend` to have access to the private member data), or use a lambda function (if you can use C++11 features) for your comparison predicate.